# Can I load the content of a JSP based on a value of input id?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts2

I have defined an ID in my JSP as

```
<input type='hidden' id='onlineStoreListingSortOrder' name='onlineStoreListingSortOrder' value='<s:property value="%{storeListingSortOrder}"/>'>
```

In the same JSP I have a select box as below

```
<div class="col-main col-sort-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 pull-right">
                                <div class="sort-bar">
                                    <select class="select-sort"  id="onlineStoreListingSortBox">
                                        <s:if test="%{value.onlineStoreListingSortOrder == "13"}">
                                        <option value="RANDOM"><label:text name="label.co.please.select" /></option>
                                        </s:if>
                                        <!--  <option value="FEATURED"><label:text name="common.featured.title" /></option> -->
                                        <option value="NAME_ASC"><label:text name="search.label.name.asc" /></option>
                                        <option value="NAME_DESC"><label:text name="search.label.name.desc" /></option>
                                        <option value="DATE_ADDED"><label:text name="search.label.date.added" /></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

Now when the page loads I want to acess the id value and put a  around first option "random". But Its not working. How can I put the condition?

Comment: You didn't post relevant code. Without this code the question is off-topic.

Comment: I have placed the JSP code in which I have to check for the condition. What else do you need, please specify, I will update accordingly. @Rom

Comment: Post the action code.

Answer (score 0):

instead of an input field, you should use set:

```
<s:set var="msg" value="%{storeListingSortOrder}" />
```

then check it, something like

```
<s:if test="#msg == 13">
```

Comment: Why to use any intermediate tag at all?

Comment: I dont know, I'm just preserving author post structure. Perhaps he needs this value after.

Comment: If they need it after they can use it again as well. :)

Comment: Only it's getting from the map value and argument type is probably string.

Comment: I will try that now. But I have one question that why can't I use input Id's value directly? Please explain.

Comment: because you are checking with struts s:if, so you will need a struts variable in order to work